# Get Current User Contacts via Ajax Request

Tags: javascript, ajax

Is there a way of fetch a current user's contact information from a canvas app via an ajax (javascript) request?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce StackExchange. Have you looked at the Canvas API? Javascript is fully available to Canvas. That being said, perhaps providing more details on how the canvas app you're referring to is being used/implemented might get you a more specific response. For example, is it displayed in a VF page? Just edit your original post to add more details since you don't have the points required to comment.